# Comprobar cadena de texto

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para leer una cadena de texto de mysqli y que si hay una palabra con "#" poder darle estilos o ponerlo en un hipervinculo

Comment: debes leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour] para comprender que debes mostrar que llevas

Answer (score 0):

No logro entender exactamente lo que estas buscando, si pudieras dar una mejor explicación seria de mucha ayuda, sin embargo si logro entender bien lo que deseas hacer podrías leer los resultados de tu consulta SQL  como comúnmente lo haces en PHP, y recorriendo cada uno de los registros podrías aplicar una expresión regular sencilla que te permita determinar si existe el signo #, y en ese caso hacer un replace del mismo por aquello que deseas, en este caso una url.

Un saludo,

Nickolas

Comment: por favor no responder hasta que el OP no mejore su pregunta, como esta ahorita es seguro se la cierren pues no es clara y además no muestra intento alguno; cosa que no es bien vista en SO en español

Comment: además lee [answer] por favor, pues tu aporte es mas un comentario que una respuesta

Comment: gracias @shadow, tienes razón, es mi segunda vez que respondo algo y sinceramente no había visto el lugar de los comentarios